# Haskell, How to create a ordered data Set a = Set [a]

Tags: haskell, set

I need to create a Haskell "data Set"

```
data Set a = Set [a]
```

Exercise
let's implement a simple Set datatype. A Set is a list of
unique elements. The set is always kept ordered.

```
Implement the functions below. You might need to add class
constraints to the functions' types.

Examples:
member 'a' (Set ['a','b','c'])  ==>  True
add 2 (add 3 (add 1 emptySet))  ==>  Set [1,2,3]
add 1 (add 1 emptySet)  ==>  Set [1]

data Set a = Set [a]
deriving (Show,Eq)
```

so far I defined :

```
-- emptySet is a set with no elements
emptySet :: Set a
emptySet = Set []

-- member tests if an element is in a set
member :: Eq a => a -> Set a -> Bool
member _ (Set[]) =  False
member a (Set (x:xs))  
    | (a == x) = True
    | otherwise = member a (Set xs)
```

but i'm struggling how to define the "add" method, it´s fail in the order test

```
-- add a member to a set
add ::  Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
add a (Set[]) = Set[a] 
add a (Set (x:xs)) 
    | (a > x) && (not ( member a (Set (x:xs)) )) = add a (Set xs)
    | (a <= x) && (not ( member a (Set (x:xs)) )) = Set ( a :(x:xs) )     
    | (not ( member a (Set (x:xs)) )) = Set ((x:xs) ++ [a])
    | otherwise = Set (x:xs)
```

Tests failed:

```
*** Failed! Falsified (after 6 tests):
add (Just 0) (Set [Nothing,Just (-5),Just 1,Just 3])
Expected: Set [Nothing,Just (-5),Just 0,Just 1,Just 3]
Was: Set [Just 0,Just 1,Just 3]
```

so my question is , how to implement the Add method but keep the order correct.
or  it's easier to using a helper function to order the elements after insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need a `member` test in each iteration of your `add` function, because you know the Set is sorted. Simply walk down the list, at each step comparing the element to be added with the front of the set. If the element to be added is equal to the smallest item, then you can stop: the element is already present. If it's less than the smallest item, then you've found its insertion point: if it's smaller than the smallest item, it must be smaller than *all* items, and thus should be added. Finally if the element to be added is larger than the smallest item, then just keep going until you find its insertion point.

Comment: so , following your line of thinking , i did 

add ::  Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
add a (Set[]) = Set[a] 
add a (Set (x:xs)) 
        | (a == x) = Set (x:xs)
        | (a < x) = Set ( a :(x:xs) )     
        | otherwise =  Set([x]) : ( add a (Set xs) )
        
but shows the error : Couldn't match expected type `[Set a]' with actual type `Set a'
                     | otherwise =  Set([x]) : ( add a (Set xs) )
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @cealex You can't `:` two `Set`s as in `Set ([x] : ...`. You can only `:` two lists. So, convert the set `add a (Set xs)` to a list (how?), prepend `x`, and then convert the final list back to a set (how?).

Comment: @chi Not two lists either, of course. Rather, one list, and one element to add to the front.

Comment: @amalloy Right! I oversimplified since the OP was starting with two sets, the first being a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You write

```
add a (Set (x:xs)) 
    | (a > x) && (not ( member a (Set (x:xs)) )) = add a (Set xs)
  --                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
....
```

`add a (Set xs)` is the result.

Where's `x`? Shouldn't it be present in the result as well?

Answer (score 1):

the solution that i'm able to found , based on the @amalloy & @chi tips , was

```
toLista :: Set a -> [a]
-- toLista (Set[]) = [] 
-- toLista (Set (x:xs)) = [x] ++ toLista ( Set (xs))

toLista (Set lista) = lista

add ::  Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
add a (Set[]) = Set[a] 
add a (Set (x:xs)) 
    | (a == x) = Set (x:xs)
    | (a < x) = Set ( a :(x:xs) )     
    | otherwise =  Set ( x : toLista ( add a (Set xs) ))
```

Comment: There is a much simpler way to implement your `toLista`, by not pattern-matching on the contents of the Set: `toLista (set xs) = xs`

Comment: Have you learned about "as patterns" or `case` expressions yet? Your second case can be written `add a Set (xxs@(x:xs)) | a == x = Set xxs | a < x = Set (a : xxs) | otherwise = ...`. I also suggest writing a "listy" version, `addList :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]`, and then wrap it: `add a (Set l) = Set (addList a l)`. This prevents you from having to fuss about applying and removing the `Set` constructor in your recursion.